# Adding a column during Excel import into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, excel-2010, import-from-excel

I have a script that creates a table as well as a column for tracking the filename that is responsible for the import.

```
select *, 'file1.xls' as 'Filename'
into dbo.SQLServerTable 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

I then need to perform additional imports which have different filenames. I don't believe this statement is syntactically correct and it is preventing the import.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SQLServerTable 
Select *, 'File2.xlsx' as 'FileName' 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel      12.0;Database=D:\Convert\Converted\File2.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Worksheet$]')
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, which one?

Comment: The error I'm getting is "String or binary data would be truncated"

Comment: Do you know in advance which columns are comping from Excel file?

Comment: Yes, everything but the filename column.  However there are roughly 109 columns.  I know I shouldn't be using the * when selecting the columns, but I really don't want to type out all 109 columns.

Comment: I believe what is happening - first `SELECT INTO` creates a table with columns of a certain VARCHAR length. When you import second file some data in that file exceed that length. You can try either `CREATE TABLE` in advance with VARCHAR(max) columns or try setting Registry option `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Access Connectivity Engine\Engines\Excel\TypeGuessRows` to 0 So excel would guess column type based on entire column and not just first 8 rows

Comment: You always have 109 columns? Then you should really take the time to create ONE table with those 109 columns (with sizes large enough to stop the truncation error), plus an additional column containing the country name. Then you only ever have to worry about one table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this problem to, this because of default tables values, for string values this would be for example a varchar(50) where i needed a varchar(120)

My solution there was to place the excel into a csv file (standard save in excel) and then use the sql Import/export UI to import the files into a table. During this process you can see all the default values and then via the advanced tab change these values to your own preferences.